# Drupal Views field handler: how to unserialize an additional field data?

Tags: views

I'm developing custom Views field handler, which renders a "Reorder" button on Commerce Line Item View. I need to access to the 'data' field, which is a serialized array.
What is the best way to get serialized field data?

```
/**
 * Implements Reorder Line Item button field.
 */
class commerce_reorder_lineitem_handler_field_commerce_reorder_lineitem_button extends views_handler_field {

       ...

          function construct() {
            parent::construct();
            $this->real_field = 'line_item_id';
            $this->additional_fields['line_item_id'] = 'line_item_id';
            $this->additional_fields['order_id'] = 'order_id';
            $this->additional_fields['data'] = 'data';
          }

          /**
           * Render form element placeholder.
           */
          function render($values) {
            return '<!--form-item-' . $this->options['id'] . '--' . $this->view->row_index . '-->';
          }

       ...
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The views data can be altered in the handler's render() method.

```
  function render($values) {
    $values->commerce_line_item_data = unserialize($values->commerce_line_item_data);
    return '<!--form-item-' . $this->options['id'] . '--' . $this->view->row_index . '-->';
  }
```

Comment: please elaborate - what the function does, and how it solves the problem

Comment: Line `$values->commerce_line_item_data = unserialize($values->commerce_line_item_data);` added to the render() method in order to unserialize fetched data.